# Precisión números float

Tags: java

En un libro que estoy leyendo pone que la precisión es aproximada de 6 dígitos.

Estos 6 dígitos a que se refiere?

Yo puedo imprimir:

```
System.out.printf("%f\n", 454333333433.333);
```

Y me da:

```
454333333433,333000
```

Me estoy liando con la mantisa y el exponente, los decimales...
Parece que es el 3330000 pero la parte no decimal?

Alguien puede aclararme esto.

Gracias.

Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 0):

> Estos 6 dígitos a que se refiere?

A los 6 dígitos más representativos del número. Los números flotantes tienen precisión limitada (32 y 64), así que no todos los números que puedas escribir se pueden representar. Lo que se hace al convertir es aproximar al número flotante más cercano.

Por ejemplo, [esta herramienta de conversión](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) nos dice que el número que escribes se guarda en formato `float` como `454333333504`.

Notarás que no coincide bien con lo que te sale, pero es el compilador de Java [está tratando tu número como un `Double`](https://ideone.com/37jubb), que tiene mayor precisión:

```
    Object obj = 454333333433.333;
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
```

Hace esto porque por defecto los literales de punto flotante los convierte a `double`. Pero si haces:

```
    System.out.printf("Float: %f\n", 454333333433.333f);
```

Obtienes `454333333504`

Comment: y por qué se obtiene 454333333504, no hemos quedado que la precisión máxima es de 6 dígitos?

Comment: Es decir, cuantas cifras significativas sin decimales se puede obtener como máximo

Comment: 6 dígitos no es la precisión máxima, es la precisión **miníma**. Es decir, que se te garantiza que al convertir tu número a `float` y aproximarlo a un valor representable, se mantendrán los 6 primeros dígitos, Si la aproximación es menor, o el número que quieres guardar puede ser representado exactamente, coincidirán más cifras (p.ej, si quieres guardar `454333333503`, se aproximará a `454333333504` y solo habrá diferencia en el último dígito. Si el número que quieres guardar es `454333333504`, ese número se puede representar exactamente y coincidirán todos los dígitos.

Comment: Y no importa que sean decimales o no, simplemente son los más dígitos más importantes, haya coma o no. Al fin y al cabo, `123456789` y `1.23456789E8` son el mismo número.

Comment: y por qué el resultado de este double System.out.printf("%f", 123456789123456789.1); es: 123456789123456784,000000. Cómo aplica el redondeo?